# Task.WaitAll never returns when it used to

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono, task

I have recently had to rewrite a console application to work on a new Mono setup (more recent version of Mono), and the code that I used before no longer works the way it should. Consider the following:

```
List<Device> devices = db_device.get();
List<Profile> profiles = db_mib.load_profiles();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
int count=0;

foreach(Device device in devices)
{
    tasks.Add(new Task((obj) =>
    {
        Device dev = null;
        try
        {
            dev = (Device)obj;
            // search profiles for a list of all profiles.
            foreach(Profile profile in profiles)
            {
                if(profile.id == dev.deviceType)
                {
                    // clone the profile and assign the mibs to the device
                    Profile temp = (Profile)profile.Clone();
                    dev.mibs = temp.mibs;
                }
            }
            snmp_get(dev);
            snmp_walk(dev);
            rrd_get(dev);
            rrd_walk(dev);
        }
        catch(KeyNotFoundException exp)
        {
            write_exception("KeyNotFoundException", dev, exp, "Caught in Main");
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException exp)
        {
            write_exception("NullReferenceException", dev, exp, "Caught in Main");
        }
        catch(AggregateException exp)
        {
            write_exception("AggregateException", dev, exp, "Caught in Main");
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException exp)
        {
            write_exception("ArgumentOutOfRangeException", dev, exp, "Caught in Main");
        }
        catch(RRDCommandException exp)
        {}
    }, device));
    tasks[count++].Start();
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("All tasks finished.");
// some more code that must run only once all tasks have finished
```

In my previous setup, I could reach "All tasks finished." However, I no longer reach that point. The tasks run and return results as they should, but it seems as though WaitAll never deems the tasks as complete. I have done some research and people are suggesting to use Task.Run instead of Task.Start. I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around what would need to be done to do that though, as it seems as though it needs to be called when creating the task versus afterward? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try clear everything inside your task, that should help you to detect if some problem happen inside your task. (or just put a return statement at the beginning of the task).
the second is create and run a task immediately with Task.Run. That should make your code more clean and easy to detect the problem.

Comment: How do I go about doing that though? Just replace my tasks.Add(new Task((obj) => with tasks.Add(Task.Run((obj) => and remove the tasks[count++].Start();?

Comment: yes, it's very easy.

Comment: Fair enough, but what about passing my device object to the task when using Task.Run? If I do that, it's expecting the second argument to be a cancellation token. Can I then just pass device to Task.Run in the sense of tasks.Add(Task.Run((device) => and then reference it directly?

Comment: Note that if you use Task.Run, there are no overload to put device object to the task. You have to create a temp variable to store device object at the beginning of foreach block and before you call Task.Run. So you can use that variable directly inside the task. Do not use the variable `device` in tasks, it's not thread safe.

Comment: @SyLe he can just use `device` variable, no need to create a temp one in this case.

Comment: So something along the lines of tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => NewFunctionToPoll(device, profiles)));?

Comment: @Evk, if he use Task.Run, so i think he must create a temp variable.

Comment: @SyLe since C# 5 foreach loop varaible can be safely captured in closure and will work "as expected". On the other hand, maybe it's still safe to create tmp variable, you might suddenly change to "for" loop later.

Comment: If I cannot pass device to Task.Run, where should I create a temp variable so that Task.Run can use the device object? Would passing it to a function (see previous comment) and cloning the device object inside of there be thread safe?

Comment: Oh, thank you @Evk, that's new to me.

Comment: @Skyline969, as @Evk said, you don't have to create a temp variable, just use the `device` one. Use this code:  `tasks.Add(new Task(()=>{});`

Comment: That's what I already do (minus passing device in as obj), and then start the task with Task.Start. However, doing so results in me being unable to reach the end of my application as Task.WaitAll never finishes. Are you suggesting that using `tasks.Add(new Task(() =>` and then referencing device directly as opposed to using dev would work?

Comment: No, it just make your code more clean. To make your code work, you have to debug on it. try to put a return statement at the beginning of task and move it step by step to the end of task. That should help you found where is the point that prevent your task to finish.